# Sql join not working on sql razor for simple db

Tags: sql, join

I am using join to get data but it shows error in syntax i am using sql razor here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contentcommenttracking 
       JOIN contentmaster 
         ON contentcommenttracking.userid = contentmaster.contentaddedbyuserid 
WHERE  username = 'imran.husain'
```

here is the error which is shown in sql razor

ERROR:

```
 Query = SELECT * from ContentCommentTracking JOIN ContentMaster
 ON ContentCommentTracking.UserID=ContentMaster.ContentAddedByUserID
 where UserName='imran.husain'
```

Here is the link I got which shows that amazon simple db does not support JOIN

http://www.packtpub.com/article/amazon-simpledb-versus-rdbms

Comment: Is UserName a field in both tables? Which is the error message?

Comment: Perhaps you have to specify "left" or "right", or "inner"?

Comment: What's the error message????

Comment: @wxyz UserName is in both tables

Comment: Did you happen to notice you still haven't specified the error message in your question?

Comment: then use either ContentCommentTracking.UserName or ContentMaster.UserName instead of simply UserName to make it work

Comment: @Leo this is the message that is shown in sql razor nothing else is shown

Comment: which database are you using?
it will also be helpful if you show the data in both tables.

Comment: @wxys done like this also but again same issue

Comment: Check if ContentCommentTracking.UserID and ContentMaster.ContentAddedByUserID have the same type

Comment: @wxys they both have the same type

Comment: @Thanks for all I just checked that amazon simple db does not support JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
        * 
FROM   
        contentcommenttracking 
    JOIN 
        contentmaster 
            ON  contentcommenttracking.userid = contentmaster.contentaddedbyuserid 
WHERE  
        contentcommenttracking.username = 'imran.husain' ;
```

Yours is ambiguous

Comment: @user3110080 Would you please add your tables structures?